# The replacement AC adapter for my Dell laptop does not charge but the old faulty one (exactly the same) does if the cord is laying just right

Tags: laptop, power-supply, dell-inspiron, adapter

I'm very frustrated and perplexed as to why the old AC adapter that clearly has a short inside somewhere will still charge the battery after I wiggle and bend the cord to find just the right spot, AND the new replacement adapter, which did charge the new replacement battery the first day I used them together, now is not recognised by my laptop and will not charge the battery but does power the laptop. Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Comment: The adapter is bad. Probably a generic adapter and not a Dell adapter. Send it back. They can power the laptop but will not charge the battery if they don’t communicate with the laptop properly.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a genuine Dell AC adapter, either it or the laptop are defective - contact Dell.

If it's a generic (not Dell brand) adapter, @Appleoddity is correct - Dell tries to lock them out by allowing the laptop to run, but not charge, from them. Get another one from Dell or from a vendor that promises it'll charge your particular Dell model.

BTW, your old adapter probably has an open in the cable, not a short.

Comment: It is a Dell adapter and as far as I can tell it has all the exact same markings, model number, etc. Is there some form of reset I can perform to make the laptop recognise the new adapter?

Comment: If it's a genuine Dell I think you have a hardware problem. Contact Dell tech support. But - be sure. I wouldn't be surprised if some dishonest vendors sell clone Dell power supplies that don't charge and aren't really made by Dell. If you got it on eBay or AliExpress or similar for an unreasonably low price, be suspicious. You're better off buying honest clones that don't claim to be Dell, but do claim to charge.